# Parboiled2 causes "missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'Prepender.class'"

Tags: scala, sbt, spray, sbt-assembly, parboiled

So I've been trying to use parboiled2 for the last few weeks now, it is possibly the most difficult dependency to add to a build I have come across in my entire life.  My current error is a compile `sbt assembly`) error:

```
[error] missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'Prepender.class'.
[error] Could not access type PrependAux in package shapeless,
[error] because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
[error] missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'Prepender.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of shapeless.
[error] .../Main.scala:56: could not find implicit value for parameter prepender: spray.routing.Prepender[shapeless.HNil,shapeless.::[String,shapeless.HNil]]
[error]     path(searchSegment / Segment)(title => get(responder(complete(
[error]                        ^
```

It seems that it is simply impossible to make Spray and Parboiled2 play nice together.

I've tried `sbt clean` and removing my `target` directories. My build file is basically this:

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "spray repo" at "http://repo.spray.io"
)

val akkaV = "2.3.6"
val sprayV = "1.3.2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  // If I comment this line, everything works fine.
  "org.parboiled" %% "parboiled" % "2.0.1" withSources() withJavadoc(),
  //
  "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.12.1" % "test" withSources() withJavadoc(),
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "2.4.15" % "test" withSources() withJavadoc(),
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2-scalacheck" % "2.4.15" % "test" withSources() withJavadoc(),
  "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.1.0" withSources() withJavadoc(),
  //
  "io.spray" %% "spray-json" % "1.3.1" withSources() withJavadoc(),
  "io.spray" %% "spray-can" % sprayV withSources() withJavadoc(),
  "io.spray" %% "spray-routing" % sprayV withSources() withJavadoc(),
  "io.spray" %% "spray-testkit" % sprayV  % "test" withSources() withJavadoc(),
  //
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaV withSources() withJavadoc(),
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % akkaV % "test" withSources() withJavadoc()
)

scalaVersion := "2.11.4"

javaOptions ++= Seq("-target", "1.8", "-source", "1.8")
```

My `sbtVersion` is 0.13.6, and my `sbt-assembly` version is 0.12.0

Before upgrading to 2.11 and upgrading my specs2 dependencies I got: [parboiled2 and Spray cause conflicting cross-version suffixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27658468/parboiled2-and-spray-cause-conflicting-cross-version-suffixes)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to use shapeless2 you need to depend on `spray-routing-shapeless2` instead of `spray-routing`.

See the example dependency declaration:

https://github.com/spray/spray-template/blob/on_spray-can_1.3_shapeless2_scala-2.11/build.sbt